# How does FileUtils.readFileToString() treat line breaks?

Tags: java, encryption, fileutils

I am writing a program in java to import a user-entered text file, encrypt it using two keywords, and write the output to a new text file.

I am using `FileUtils.readFileToString()` to read the text file into a String, but I don't understand how it treats line breaks/return keys. What character does it convert them into?

I need to understand this, so I can encrypt this character and then it can be decrypted properly.

I am essentially trying to add a 'line break symbol' to my 'characters' String.

EDIT: Problem solved, using '/n'. I finally understand it. Thank you!

Comment: If you are referring to the `FileUtils` in Apache Commons IO, then Apache is open source and you can just look at the source yourself to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. Being a complete beginner, though, I really don't know what I'm looking for over there... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no special handling for line breaks. `FileUtils#readFileToString` consumes the bytes inside the file, interpreting them with whichever character encoding you provide to produce a `String` value. If there are bytes in the file that correspond to a new line or carriage return in the character set provided, then you'll have a new line or carriage return in the returned `String`.

You can find the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.2/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#FileUtils.readFileToString%28java.io.File%2Cjava.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks. What I don't understand though, being a complete beginner, is how I would go about including that code (in UTF8 or similar) into my string of characters (basically the alphabet + other common characters) that is used for the encryption.

Comment: @petrus Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm asking if there is a way to include a 'line break symbol' inside a string. I will add my code in a second because I don't think I'm explaining it well.

Comment: @petrus The literals `"\n"` and `"\r\n"` represent line breaks on different OS's.

Comment: Thank you. What I am trying to ask (and it is probably a stupid question) is how I can use indexOf() to find the character 'linebreak' in my 'characters' string as I would for, for example, the character '.'

Comment: @petrus `'.'` is a character, so is `'\n'`. `'\r'` is another character. `"\r\n"` is a `String` literal with two characters.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I think I finally get it... :) I've added '\n' to the 'characters' string and it all works now :)